# fsck failed on all (unrelated) servers

Tags: boot, 20.04, fsck

I am curios how this happens?  I came in from the weekend and had to reboot two **unrelated** servers, exhibiting the same similar message:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.26.2
/dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
/dev/sda1: Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.

/dev/sda1: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sda1 requires a manual fsck

Busybox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) _
```

Both servers I had to run `fsck` manually, and both were easily repaired.  The question is, one being a database server (production), and the other is a web development (non production) server.  How does this happen? Both were running when I came into work .. And both failed at reboot.  These are virtual drives btw ... Using VMWare ESXI Hypervisor.

I thought maybe an "unclean" shut down (power off) but the machines were running, and simply would not reboot until the `fsck` was completed.

**UPDATE**  I just ran `fsck` on another non-production server in the same Hypervisor Application -- This makes 3 servers:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Warning!  /dev/mapper/ywpData--vg-root is mounted.
Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
/dev/mapper/ywpData--vg-root: clean, 384516/6266880 files, 16531831/25039872 blocks
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Warning!  /dev/sda1 is mounted.
/dev/sda1 was not cleanly unmounted, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Free blocks count wrong (100531, counted=295192).
Fix? no

Free inodes count wrong (124599, counted=124616).
Fix? no

/dev/sda1: 329/124928 files (16.1% non-contiguous), 398157/498688 blocks
```

Comment: Since these are all VM Guests, are they all on the same Host?

Comment: ESXI is a cloud of hosts --  So technically, yes ..  although the hardware is "fluid"

Comment: Can strange happenings in physical drives (hot swaps etc) cause this sort of error on virtual drives?  I though virtual drives were impervious to physical hardware failure.